# Check if day with time is passed

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I want to get the next wednesday for example. And I have some great working code for it, see the code below.

```
getCorrectDay : function (dayINeed){
        const today = moment().isoWeekday();

// if we haven't yet passed the day of the week that I need:
        if (today <= dayINeed) {
          // then just give me this week's instance of that day
          return moment().isoWeekday(dayINeed);
        } else {
          // otherwise, give me *next week's* instance of that same day
          return moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayINeed);
        }
      },
```

But I want to include a time in it, it needs to check on 2PM CET, but I don't know how to do that properly, with the different time zone's etc. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: to make your life easier, i suggest you have moment.js i try

Comment: @KornholioBeavis Im using moment.js already in my example above :)

Comment: Have you tried working with the moment timezone plugin?